# How many times a event fired in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

**If you have 10 users requesting your application
,How many time Application_Start event will be fired?**

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Did you try testing? What happened?

Comment: Questions like that are *VERY* easy to answer by checking the documentation of the event or just googling. It's faster than writing the SO question

Comment: **I'm a beginner on stack overflow.I will be reduce or remove my fault as now i'm still.** @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Satya then you should have taken the tour and checked [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This isn't about rules though - there's a ton of documentation and tutorials on MSDN. The fastest way to find an answer is to check the documentation or just googling. You'll notice there are 4 downvotes and 3 questions with direct links to the docs

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on the event. Things like `Application_Start` should be called only once per application domain, which is usually delineated per application pool unless you share pools.

Comment: In the web garden scenario, it will be called more than one time per application pool.

Comment: Which is why I said usually. As you point out there's cases outside of this.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on the [ASP.NET lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx). Its called once.

```
Application_Start
```

> Called when the first resource (such as a page) in an ASP.NET
>   application is requested. The Application_Start method is called only
>   **one time** during the life cycle of an application. You can use this
>   method to perform startup tasks such as loading data into the cache
>   and initializing static values.

Answer (score 0):

Application_Start() event is a bit different than other entry points (Main, Startup, etc.) in ASP.NET.
It does not fire per request, per session or per user.

The event will fire once per application pool worker as soon as it is started, which happens when the first user tries to access the application (or first X users if it's a web garden). If your application is configured to stay "Always On" then the event will be fired as soon as IIS starts.

Answer (score 0):

**Application_Start** event raise when the first instance of the HttpApplication class is created.

> And while development or for any reason you change the **web.config**
>   file and save changes it will force the application to be re-started.
>
> Whenever your application restarted/started **Application_Start**
>   event will be raised.

For more details follow this : [Application Life Cycle in General](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)